# How to automatically click "li class=" with vbs?

Tags: css, vba, internet-explorer

I've been trying to click this button that I used F12 to find the `li class` for but I cannot click it using `IE.Document.getElementByid().Click`

> How would I go about doing this?

This is the button:

```
li class="x-tab-with-icon navigator-tab" id=object_main_navigation__productNavigation
```

Comment: This has been answered a number of times on SO. See which answer best fits your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+click+ie+link

Comment: part of the command is _getElementByid()_ .  do you think that something may be missing?  hint: you are telling your code to click on **nothing**

Comment: That's just the command I am using, I've used IE.Document.getElementByid(object_main_navigation__productNavigation).Click but it doesn't work